# How does selection sort work?

Tags: c++, sorting

This is a selection sort that I'm trying and I don't understand why it isn't working.  My understanding is that selection sort scans a vector for the smallest value which when it finds it moves it to the beginning of the vector.  It preforms another scan this time ignoring the first element and doing it all over again until  n - 1 times where n is the length of the vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>
using namespace std;





int main()
{
    vector <string> vName, vID, vClass;
    string sName, minValue, sID, sClass, sSearch, sQuestion, ssSearch, sSearchN, sSearchI;
    int iSize, iStudent;
    // Display initial vector size
    iSize = vName.size();

    cout << "Student list starts with the size:" << iSize << endl;

    // Get size of list from user

    cout << "How many students would you like to add?" << endl;
    cin >> iStudent;
    cin.ignore();
    // Get names, ids, and classes

    for (int i = 0; i < iStudent; i++)
    {
        cout << "Student" << i + 1 << ":\n";
        cout << "Please enter the student name: ";
        getline(cin, sName);
        vName.push_back(sName);

        cout << "Enter ID number ";
        getline(cin, sID);
        vID.push_back(sID);

        cout << "Enter class name ";
        getline(cin, sClass);
        vClass.push_back(sClass);

    }
    // Display header

    cout << "The list of students has the size of: " << iStudent << endl;
    cout << "The Student List" << endl;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Name:" << setw(30) << "ID:" << setw(38) << "Enrolled Class : " << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------";
    cout << "\n";

    // for loop for displying list
    for (int x = 0; x < vName.size() && vID.size() && vClass.size(); x++)
    {

        cout << vName[x] << "\t \t \t" << vID[x] << "\t \t \t" << vClass[x] << endl;
    }

    // Sorting function and for loop to display sorted names
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "The Student List after Sorting:" << endl;
    cout << "\n";


    //*************************************
    int startScan, minIndex;


    for (startScan = 0; startScan < vName.size() - 1; startScan++)
    {
        minIndex = startScan;
        minValue = vName[startScan];
        for (int index = startScan + 1; index < vName.size(); index++)
        {
            if (vName[index] < minValue)
            {
                minValue = vName[index];
                minIndex = index;
            }
        }
        vName[minIndex] = vName[startScan];
        vName[startScan] = minValue;
        vID[minIndex] = vID[startScan];
        vID[startScan] = minValue;
        vClass[minIndex] = vClass[startScan];
        vClass[startScan] = minValue;

    }


    //******************


    //sort(vName.begin(), vName.end());

    //for (int y = 0; y < vName.size(); y++)
    //{
    //  cout << vName[y] << endl;
    //}

    cout << "\n";

    // Search function uses a do while loop that loops so long as the user inputs a "y" or "Y"


    do
    {
        int iPick;
        cout << "Search Menu:" << endl;
        cout << "1. By Name\n";
        cout << "2. By ID\n \n";
        cin >> iPick;
        if (iPick == 1)
        {
            cout << "Please Enter a name to be searched:" << endl;
            getline(cin >> ws, sSearchN);
            if (binary_search(vName.begin(), vName.end(), sSearchN))
            {



                cout << sSearchN << " was found." << endl << endl;
            }


            else
            {

                cout << sSearchN << " was not found." << endl << endl;


            }

            cout << "Would you like to search another name?" << endl << endl;
            cout << vName[0];
            cout << "Please enter Y for Yes and N for No:" << endl << endl;
            getline(cin >> ws, sQuestion);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Please Enter an ID to be searched:" << endl;
            getline(cin >> ws, sSearchI);
            if (binary_search(vID.begin(), vID.end(), sSearchI))
            {
                cout << sSearchI << " " << "was found"  << endl << endl;
                cout << "Please enter Y for Yes and N for No:" << endl << endl;
                getline(cin >> ws, sQuestion);
            }
            else
            {
                cout << sSearchI << " " << "was not found." << endl << endl;
                cout << "Please enter Y for Yes and N for No:" << endl << endl;
                getline(cin >> ws, sQuestion);
            }
        }

    } while (sQuestion == "Y" || sQuestion == "y");


    cout << "Thank you for using this program!" << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

EDIT: posted whole program

So the issue is it doesn't sort at all, just gives back vName unsorted.

Comment: Good attempt on a "complete program", but it isn't a complete program that compiles. Also, could you describe WHAT isn't working? Does it not sort correctly, crashes, or something else?

Comment: is it even compiling ? Because that does not even look like a valid c++ program, no main()

Comment: Sorry i was just trying to post the relevant part, basically it is not sorting the vName vector you get them back in the manner which you filled the vector.

Comment: What makes you think it's not sorting correctly? I suggest you carefully examine the sequence of operations in your code. (i.e. the printing, relative to the sorting)

Comment: I guess what i should've been asking is how come it doesn't sort all 3 vectors according to how the first vector vName isn't sorted.  When i uncomment this for '(int y = 0; y < vName.size(); y++)' and display a cout with vName[y], vID[y] and vClass[y] it goes crazy.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley big thanks to you man, looking at it over and over and trying to figure out how it works line by line made me see the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay upon more further study of the code I think I've figured it out.

So looking at the part of the code that is sorting, the way that it works is actually pretty simple.  `startScan` is an int increments until it becomes equal to the size of the vector in the for loop.  In this case it is `vName`. minIndex will hold the smallest index number which at the time of initialization will be equal to the `starScan`.  Finally `minValue` is a string (in this case because we have a vector of strings) that acts as a temporary container for the element at vName[scanStart].  In the second for loop index will be incremented through the vector and will test if the element vName[index] is smaller than the temproray container i talked about earlier.  If it is than the new temp will be vName[index] after that is done it will exit the inner loop and update and move on to the next smallest value in vName.  Understanding this it's easy to make it so that the sorting happens with 2 other vectors.  All one has to do is create containers for those vectors like the ones i have here `minValueA` and `minValueB`.  They will simply be changing as vName changes.  That way everything stays in the order in which vName is ordered.  I hope that helps someone!

```
int startScan, minIndex;
string minValue, minValueA, minValueB;


    for (startScan = 0; startScan < vName.size() - 1; startScan++)
    {
        minIndex = startScan;
        minValue = vName[startScan];
        minValueA = vID[startScan];
        minValueB = vClass[startScan];

        for (int index = startScan + 1; index < vName.size(); index++)
        {
            if (vName[index] < minValue)
            {
                minValue = vName[index];
                minValueA = vID[index];
                minValueB = vClass[index];
                minIndex = index;

            }
        }
        vName[minIndex] = vName[startScan];
        vName[startScan] = minValue; //values for vName are being added to the other ones.
        vID[minIndex] = vID[startScan];
        vID[startScan] = minValueA;
        vClass[minIndex] = vClass[startScan];
        vClass[startScan] = minValueB;

    }

    //******************


    sort(vName.begin(), vName.end());

    for (int y = 0; y < vName.size(); y++)
    {
        cout << vName[y] << "\t \t \t " << vID[y] << "\t \t \t " << vClass[y] << endl;
    }
```